# Python cx_oracle ignores numbers by positional bind variables

Tags: python, cx-oracle

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM t WHERE c1=:2 AND c2=:1", (1, 2))
```

is executed as

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE c1=1 AND c2=2
```

instead of

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE c1=2 AND c2=1
```

as I expected. Why?

In fact all the :numbers are completely ignored

```
sql = ":5, :0, :0, :2, :1, :3"
```

is interpreted the same as

```
sql = ":1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6"
```

Is this by intention or a bug?

Comment: I guess cx_oracle counts those bindings always the same way, starting with 1. You can use named bindings, though. I find them much clearer, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cx_Oracle is using OCI which has this behavior. You can read about it in this white paper (bottom of page 14 and top of page 15):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/php/whatsnew/building-best-drivers-131920.pdf

Effectively Oracle scans from left to right and assigns position numbers to bind variables in the order they are encountered. You can use named bind variables instead to avoid this potential confusion.

Comment: Thank you Anthony, one will expect this dangerous behavior will be at least mentioned in the cx_Oracle documentation.

Comment: I'm not sure I would call this behaviour dangerous but I have included a note about this in the cx_Oracle documentation so that others aren't surprised like you were!

Comment: Finally I realized there is a check mark :) I spent several extra weeks by rewriting my mini ORM because of this. Unfortunately the SQL Developer is treating these positional numbers as keyword arguments, so I have recognized this "bug" at the very end. I expected it works the same way as python string format which seems natural to me.

Comment: I can see how it would be confusing, especially with SQL Developer treating it differently! Glad you figured things out and hopefully the snippet in the documentation will help others.